# PHP PDO query after a LINK click

Tags: php, hyperlink

Is it possible to activate a SQL query after clicking a link?

By the way, not really looking into using Ajax. The whole page needs to go to the new page, but the query also needs to function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just run the query on load of the page you're calling?

Comment: Because its a notification system. Need the SQL to be done before the page. Otherwise the user can go to the page without looking at their notifications and it'll delete the notification.